# What are some of user authentication methods for Laravel API server?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, authorization

Building API backend in Laravel for React.js SPA and React-Native mobile app. Previously I'd use Laravel/ui auth system but now when I'm doing SPA over APIs it's not quite simple anymore so I have issues of developing the authentication.
Saw many tutorials and forums but most of them do the most basic hashed password + token. But doing just username check then password verification check and generating a token seems rather unsafe.
What are best practices for actually doing user authentication for APIs? Or is there some package to ease things so I don't have to reinvent something that is already hard enough?

Comment: Look into JWT authentication. See https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/

Comment: `... a token seems rather unsafe`? Why? Have you looked into how it works? Also, this question will likely generate opinions rather than concrete answers. You should edit it and ask a specific question instead of asking "What is the best...?"

Answer (score 2):

Here are some:

- [JWT](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/)
- [Laravel Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/passport#main-content)
- [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum)

In general, checking the username and password matching doesn't have to be unsafe if you implement a good password validation policy (Checking numbers, uppercase, lowercase). But if you're really have high security requirements for your application you can implement 2FA (Two Factors Authentication).

[Laravel Fortify](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#two-factor-authentication) can help you with this.